# Python: What is the default handling of SIGTERM?

Tags: python, signals, sigterm

What does Python do under the covers by default if it receives a SIGTERM but there is no signal handler registered for it?

Comment: Sorry to say that the bounty here has been wasted, as *nothing changed* and Thomas Wouters' answer is *still correct* for current Python versions, including 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: Terminate an interruption of signals.

Answer (score 36):

Building on the answer of Thomas Wouters, python does not register a handler for the SIGTERM signal.  We can see this by doing:

```
In[23]: signal.SIG_DFL == signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,signal.SIG_DFL)
Out[23]: True
```

That means that the system will take the default action.  On linux, the default action (according to [the signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) for a SIGTERM is to terminate the process.

Terminating a process means that:

- the process will simply not be allocated any more time slices during which it can execute code.

  - This means that it will not raise an exception, or call the code in try: finally: blocks, or the `__exit__` method of context managers.  It will not do those things because that particular python interpreter will never get the chance to execute another instruction.
- The process's memory and other resources (open files, network sockets, etc...) will be released back to the rest of the system.

Comment: This is so true, important and - at least to me - unintuitive. I thought the whole business of finally clauses and \__exit__ methods of context-managers was to make sure the code in question is always run (except a SIGKILL, which I was aware of is handled on a system level). Struggled several days with this and only now came to the realization that you already presented here in your answer. I need to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 25):

Nothing. Python itself does not register a signal handler for it. You can check this in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import signal
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_DFL)
0
>>> signal.SIG_DFL
0
```

That shows `signal.signal()` returning signal.SIG_DFL for `signal.SIGTERM`. Contrast it with `signal.SIGINT`, which does have a default signal handler (which raises `KeyboardInterrupt`):

```
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
<built-in function default_int_handler>
```

Comment: This also means that functions registered via `atexit.register()` won't be called if the process is terminated by `SIGTERM`.

Comment: Ok fine, but what does it DO? Exit uncleanly? Ignore it completely? Something else?

Comment: Immediately dies. Python just completely ignores the signal, and therefore dies immediately. Python does not "do" anything. That's my own reading/understanding of what people are saying above. Someone can feel free to chime in and correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: (presumably however, we could register our own handler that does raise a normal exception?)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
import time

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__()")

    def __del__(self):
        print("A.__del__()")

a = A()
b = A()

time.sleep(10)
```

Under normal circumstances, the output would be:

```
A.__init__()
A.__init__()
A.__del__()
A.__del__()
```

But if you kill it with SIGTERM you get:

```
A.__init__()
A.__init__()
Terminated
```

Thus the program does not terminate cleanly (the destructors are not called).

Comment: Yes, that is the default action when a process doesn't register a SIGTERM handler. And that's what Thomas Wouters' answer tells us already, and stochastic makes explicit.